# DayNightTheme works on one app but not the other?

Tags: java, android

I am having a very baffling time trying to figure this theming issue out. I have two separate apps, both of which have identical styles xml, night color, and not night color files. They both have tinted vector drawables as the drawable. The thing being that one crashes, one doesn't. It should also be noted that the app only crashes on Android 5.0. Anything above works and kitkat seems to work as well.

Here is the crash report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nick.mowen.materialdesignplugin/com.nick.mowen.materialdesign.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:404)
       at android.app.Activity.onApplyThemeResource(Activity.java:3683)
       at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:140)
       at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:85)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setTheme(AppCompatActivity.java:89)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:81)
       at com.nick.mowen.materialdesign.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:85)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Here is the night colors xml which is causing crashes - interestingly, right now the nav drawer color is causing crashes when set to #212121, yet when it is set to @android:color/black it works fine:

```
<resources>>

    <color name="color_primary_dark">#212121</color>
    <color name="accent_primary">@color/accent_material_dark</color>
    <color name="back_primary">#FF303030</color>
    <color name="list_selected_primary">@color/accent_material_dark_selected</color>
    <color name="text_third">@android:color/tertiary_text_dark</color>
    <color name="text_second">@android:color/secondary_text_dark</color>
    <color name="text_main">@android:color/primary_text_dark</color>
    <color name="drawable_tint">@null</color>
    <color name="dialog_back">#424242</color>
    <color name="action_primary">#212121</color>
    <color name="inverse_text_third">@android:color/tertiary_text_light</color>
    <color name="inverse_text_second">@android:color/secondary_text_light</color>
    <color name="inverse_text_main">@android:color/primary_text_light</color>
    <bool name="dark_status">false</bool>
    <color name="navigation_primary">#212121</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: Have any idea what attribute that is referring to?

Comment: Is there a way for me to check which one?

Comment: If drawable_tint is an attribute of type "color", I would not set it to null because a color is always an int. Use transparent instead (#000000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at AOSP's 5.0 code (http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java)

and this is is the method being called:

```
@Override
protected void onApplyThemeResource(Resources.Theme theme, int resid,
        boolean first) {
    if (mParent == null) {
        super.onApplyThemeResource(theme, resid, first);
    } else {
        try {
            theme.setTo(mParent.getTheme());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Empty
        }
        theme.applyStyle(resid, false);
    }

    // Get the primary color and update the TaskDescription for this activity
    if (theme != null) {
        TypedArray a = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Theme);
        int colorPrimary = a.getColor(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Theme_colorPrimary, 0);
        a.recycle();
        if (colorPrimary != 0) {
            ActivityManager.TaskDescription v = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(null, null,
                    colorPrimary);
            setTaskDescription(v);
        }
    }
}
```

The line that is crashing is the `getColor`. It seems that the color that you have specified for your particular theme cannot be resolved to a color. Check your resources and confirm that it can be resolved to a color via the API [(TypedArray).getColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getColor(int,%20int)):

Note what it says about the error:

> UnsupportedOperationException if the attribute is defined but is not
>   an **integer color** or **color state list**.

Comment: Thanks for this! All the colors are hex codes besides one which is @null for the dark theme.

Comment: Trying adding a reference to an android color just for debugging. Becasue if getColor can't resolve it it will crash.

Comment: Ok, I did that and got them all to a point where they work. Then I removed the first one and it is where I set the tertiary text color to: #66000000 and #80FFFFFF which shows as a valid color in the preview, unless 5.0 can't handle that?

Comment: Can you post both resources for the color and how they are referenced by your manifest?

Comment: updated with the night color xml, read my note as well, this is a very peculiar issue it seems. It is almost like it is just the fact that the color is in the other xml rather than the fact that it isn't working correctly that causes the crash. Update #2: I just added the navigation color to the main colors.xml as well and now that crash is resolved, is that the issue?

Comment: I think the problem is you aren't specifying a from argb which looks like 0x00000000 for reference android black is 0x0106000c and they specify argb.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out! I was being stupid, here is the summary (thanks for your help btw!) So basically I have a theme which has a background as a drawable (as a splash screen). The issue being I forgot to set the theme back to the DayNightTheme, so it was referencing colors that didn't exist. Marking this as an answer since it led me to the solution